# How to put timestamps in local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, timestamp, local-storage

Hello I am creating an chrome extension and I am trying to put all my timestamps that a retrieved after visiting a url into an array in local storage but I am having trouble doing so. It continues to update timestamps and i want all my timestamps to stay the same. However it doesnt seem to save anything and i keep receiving this error. Do anyone know how to fix this error or what may be causing it.

[image: error]

```
function addRow() {

    //SavaDataToLocalStorage(data);
    
        //putting dates in array-- works somewhat
            
            
            //var myDate = data[data.length-1];
            //data.length = 0;
    
    const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()    
    Object.keys(bg.get).forEach(function (url) {
    
    
        // Append product to the table
            var data = [];
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')) || [];
            // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
            data.push( Date.now() );
            localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(data));
            myDate = data;
        
            //protocol
            var arr = url.split("/");
            var protocoll = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
        
            //inputed data --
            browser= "Google Chrome"; 
            protocol = protocoll;
            downloads = "example";
            description = "example";
            //use data or myDate as time
            time = myDate;
            //have as Date.now()
                
        
        //will put dates in array and replace it and have var as myDate
    // add new row to the table
                  //1 = in the top 
                  //table.rows.length = the end
                  //table.rows.length/2+1 = the center 

            var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
            
            //console.log(table.rows.length) gives length of table
                  
                  // add cells to the row
                  var browserCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  var protocolCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
                  var downloadsCell = newRow.insertCell(4);
                  var descCell = newRow.insertCell(5);
                  
                  // add the data to the cells
                  
                  urlCell.innerHTML = `${url}`; 
                  timeCell.innerHTML = time;
                    browserCell.innerHTML = browser;
                    descCell.innerHTML = description;
                    protocolCell.innerHTML = protocol;
                    downloadsCell.innerHTML = downloads;
                  console.log("add row works");
     }) 
            }
```

Comment: What is the `localStorage.getItem('session')` if you console.log it?  Also can you please show us more context?  Your image of the error reflects that a parse is being done inside a forEach call

Comment: @Taplar I added more context and fixed the typo. Its within the function addrow(). I still receive the same error And nothing is currently in my 'session'.

Answer (score 3):

Fix typo on line:5 date>>>data

```js
 var data = [];
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')) || [];
    // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
    data.push( Date.now() );
    localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(data));
    myDate = data;

    //inputed data
    time = myDate;
```